# How to make dividers in navbar like breadcrumb?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to make "dividers" between links in navbar **automatically**.

> before: Home Library Logout 
>   after: Home / Library  / Logout

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

and check example at **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/EgjNBj?editors=1100)**

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">WORK</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">BUSINESS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.navbar a {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li:after {
  content: "/";
}

ul li:last-child:after {
  content: "";
}
```

I hope it helps you

Comment: Yep, I know. But I want those separators in side of the links in navbar, not in an "ol" tag. Thanks, anyway :)

Comment: Works fine! Thanks!